# Correcting specific non normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, multilevel-analysis, bias-correction

I have run a multilevel model (time series cross section data; xtmixed) and am checking if the assumptions hold. Given the non-normality of my residuals, and after having corrected potential linearity issues, it seems I would need to manipulate my dependent variable to meet regression's requirements.

Here is the distribution of my DV:

[image]

My ideas so far are:
- relying on hints form sigmoid curves (but I am really not familiar with that);
- recodifying my DV to create a categorical variable out of a continuous variable.

**EDITING MY OWN QUESTION:**

Here is how the distribution of my residuals look like:

[image]

Should I worry about it?

**EDITING Bis**

And here is my Q-normal plot for response var

[image]

Comment: Before you do all that you should ask yourself: 1) How important is it really that my error be normal in this context? and 2) is what I have close enough?  Unless you are trying to do really fancy forecasting stuff or if your sample is very small, the answer to the above two questions are 1) not very and 2) maybe, but use a bootstrap to be sure.  Your coefficient estimates do not require normality to be consistent.  What you should be worried about are your standard errors (those assume normality).  The correct bootstrap can estimate std. error without any normality assumption.

Comment: Of course my above comment assumes things, like; you already considered the effect of outliers, made appropriate transformations to the data where it made sense (i.e. log-levels) and other stuff along the lines of "corrected potential linearity issues".  Also if you have panel data and do plan to use a bootstrap be sure to use the right one...

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld : Thank you so much for your help. Indeed I've checked the basic linearity assumptions. The thing is that my sample is not so big: I have 26 cases over six time points, which is reasonable but which makes me more confident if the assumptions hold properly. I'll look into bootstraps options then. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Absent any details about your dataset or the specific model you fitted, there is not much to say. But your kernel density estimate may be concealing as much as it is revealing: it seems as if you may have two spikes there which are just being smoothed out. A quantile-normal plot is more likely to hint at any pathologies in your data.

Comment: @Nick Cox : I'm adding the q-normal plot. Here is the model I run. Since I compiled myself the dataset, I'm not sure it helps..  All variables are continuous but bounded: xtmixed totspe eb incent npish immpop mipex wgieff || ctry: date , reml

Comment: Thanks; that does help. Two reactions: Your response variable may well be positive by definition, which doesn't match your model choice of linear regression. (I wasn't clear enough: I wanted to see a quantile plot of your response most of all.) I think you have a quite a lot of predictors there for a rather small dataset.

Comment: @NickCox : I thought of opting for an ordered probit and recoding my response variable but I would be afraid to lose precious information. As for the number of variables, I agree. I will test different models adding or removing some of these. And above, you'll find the qnorm plot for my response variable. Thank you for your help

Comment: Based on the qnorm plot, it does look like a sigmoid response curve. Given that, it might be worth exploring the class of nonlinear mixed effects models developed by Weiss in these lecture notes... http://www.unc.edu/courses/2008fall/ecol/563/001/docs/lectures/lecture27.htm

Comment: I see in the distribution a spike at zero and the remaining distribution all positive values. Linear regression is not a good idea for these situations It's hard to be confident about what would work better: see e.g. literature on two-part models, Poisson regression (even if the response is not a counted variable), etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your messages, that's most helpful! I will now look into non linear models and poisson regression, two-parts models and so on

Comment: Alternatively, and more crucially, if this is a bounded measure (0 to 100%), then some kind of logit makes much more sense here. You are evidently using Stata: see `fracreg`.

Comment: Yes! I was sure something of the like already existed. I think this may fit particularly well. Ok, I will dig into all those inputs. Thank you all